# Magento 2 View Cart & Checkout page - Continue Shopping redirect to previous page

Tags: magento2, onestepcheckout

We want the continue shopping button in the view cart and one step checkout page to redirect to the previous page not the homepage. We have requested this customization from several vendors who tell us they cannot do this. Is this not possible in Magento 2? If it is possible can someone explain how to code this?